# HighCharts - compare series with values instead of percentage

Tags: highcharts

Just a simple answer needed, is there a simple way to compare a series on values rather than percentages? Something like "compare : 'values'" rather than "compare : 'percent'" or do I manually have to add data points for given time intervals? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but the option is called `value`

From the [plotOptions.series.compare](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.compare) documentation:

> compare: String
>   Compare the values of the series against
>   the first value in the visible range. **The y axis will show percentage
>   or absolute change depending on whether compare is set to "percent" or
>   "value"**. When this is applied to multiple series, it allows comparing
>   the development of the series against eachother. Defaults to
>   undefined.

The demos from the documentation: Setting compare to [`percent`](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/series-compare-percent/), [`value`](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/series-compare-value/).