# Change yAxis values in Compare multiple series highstock for showing point value instead of percentage change value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I am using Highstock Chart [compare](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare)

```
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },

        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                }
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent',
                showInNavigator: true
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2,
            split: true
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    });
}
```

[image]

As we can see the y axis has values 0%,20%,40%, can we have the values which represents the point values `point.y` (like 50,100,150) instead of `point.change`(0%,20%,40%,) in `yAxis`.

Requirement is to show actual values instead of percentage change in `yAxis`.

```
labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
            }
        },
```

I think currently `this.value` in yAxis label is percentage change `point.change`, can we show value which represent `point.y`.

Is this possible to do

**Note y-axis value should not be hard coded**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HighCharts - compare series with values instead of percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207017/highcharts-compare-series-with-values-instead-of-percentage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `series` like that :

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    //compare: 'percent',
    compare: 'value',
    showInNavigator: true
  }
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dtg5z4e/)

Comment: thanks for guiding me. https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.compare